# Why PageScalingFactor doesn't affect anything?

Tags: c#, wpf, printing

I try to dynamically create and silently print a document.
The problem is that I need to scale document to fit page.  I try to use PrintTicket.PageScalingFactor but it doesn't work: when printer prints the document there is no difference between PageScalingFactor=50 and PageScalingFactor=250. PageScalingFactor doesn't affect anything.
Here's a code fragment:
Creating PrintTickets:

```
PrintTicket tkt = new PrintTicket();

tkt.Collation = Collation.Uncollated;
tkt.CopyCount = 1;
tkt.DeviceFontSubstitution = DeviceFontSubstitution.On;
tkt.Duplexing = Duplexing.OneSided;
tkt.InputBin = InputBin.AutoSelect;
tkt.OutputColor = OutputColor.Monochrome;
tkt.PageMediaSize = new PageMediaSize(PageMediaSizeName.ISOA9);
tkt.PageMediaType = PageMediaType.Unknown;
tkt.PageOrder = PageOrder.Standard;
tkt.PageOrientation = PageOrientation.Portrait;
tkt.PageResolution = new PageResolution(PageQualitativeResolution.Draft);
tkt.PageScalingFactor = 40;
tkt.PagesPerSheet = 1;
tkt.TrueTypeFontMode = TrueTypeFontMode.DownloadAsOutlineFont;


StackPanel myPanel = new StackPanel();
myPanel.Margin = new Thickness(15);
```

setting up PrintQueue and filling StackPanel with data doesn't matter
Printing:

```
myPanel.Measure(new Size(dialog.PrintableAreaWidth,
                         dialog.PrintableAreaHeight));
myPanel.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(0, 0),
                myPanel.DesiredSize));

dial2.PrintVisual(myPanel, "A Great Image.");
```

I set PageScalingFactor 40, 100, 250 - output is the same.
What should I do?

Comment: Did you have any success in this? I have the same problem

Comment: Same problem here, someone have a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Is the PageScaling feature set to CustomSquare?

Comment: Setting PageScaleFactor itself sets  PageScaling feature to CustomSquare (MSDN: "PageScaling feature in the PrintTicket XML document is set to CustomSquare"), isn't it?